# WP_Query based on multiple metadata comparisons

Tags: custom-field, wp-query

I have created a custom post type with custom fields and I need to filter them based on several meta data values.

```
$args = array(
       'post_type' => 'match_report',
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'meta_key' => 'report_type',
       'meta_value' => 'cup',
       'meta_query' => array(
           'relation' => 'OR',
              array(
                 'key' => 'report_home-select',
                 'value' => $team_id,
                 'compare' => '=',
              ),
              array(
                 'key' => 'report_away-select',
                 'value' => $team_id,
                 'compare' => '='
              )
       )                                  
     );

    $reports = new WP_Query($args);
```

Basically I want to create a meta query that has a relation of OR and AND. So in English I want the all the match reports with the `report_type` 'cup' that have either the `report_home-select` key with the value of a specific team_id OR the `report_away-select` key with the same value. I hope that makes sense. In essence I want a double relation.

Answer (score 0):

You could split this into two WP_Querys:

```
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'match_report',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'meta_key' => 'report_type',
   'meta_value' => 'cup',
   'fields' => 'ids'                                 
 );

$reportsPre = new WP_Query($args);
$post_IDs = array();
if(isset($reportsPre->posts) && !empty($reportsPre->posts)){
  foreach((array) $reportsPre->posts as $id) {
    $post_IDs[] = $id;
  }
}

$args2 = array(
   'post__in' => array($post_IDs),
   'meta_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'OR',
          array(
             'key' => 'report_home-select',
             'value' => $team_id,
             'compare' => '=',
          ),
          array(
             'key' => 'report_away-select',
             'value' => $team_id,
             'compare' => '='
          )
   ));

  $reports = new WP_Query($args2);
```

I'm not near a computer where I could test this but it should work.

Comment: It didn't but I see what you mean. So I have to use a nested query of sorts? I'll see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Any luck?  have you tried using LIKE as the compare operator?

Comment: I did but no luck :( I decided to create custom taxonomies in the end. Works like a charm now but I am still curious about how to solve the original problem. Thanks for your help.